# I need help to display first 100 Fibonacci numbers without array in C++

Tags: c++

I am not allowed to use array.

My code works fine up to some point when it suddenly shows negative numbers:

```
...
4660046610375530309
7540113804746346429
-6246583658587674878
```

Why is that and how do I fix it (without arrays or additional libraries) ?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  long long int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3, i, number;
  cout << "Enter the number of elements: ";
  cin >> number;
  cout << n1 << "\n" << n2 << "\n"; // printing 0 and 1
  // loop starts from 2 because 0 and 1 are already printed
  for (i = 2; i < number; ++i) {
    n3 = n1 + n2;
    cout << n3 << "\n";
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n3;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your code?

Comment: what help do you need? If there is something wrong with your code, please include a [mcve] and explain whats wrong with it

Comment: Note that the 100th Fibonacci number won't fit in typical `long long int` (64-bit long).

Comment: If you run the code you will see for large numbers it will display negative numbers

Comment: at some point it overflows, but otherwise its fine https://godbolt.org/z/sEzWhvfY3. Are  you worried about that "strange" negative results?

Comment: you can try `unsigend long long`, but that will just shift the limit a little. For bigger numbers you need some bigint type that can represent such large integers. Please note that the question should be selfcontained. `long long int` is not the same on every platform, hence you need to tell us what output you get

Comment: The 100:th Fibonacci number has 69 binary digits. Most implementations do not have a wide enough integer type. This is impossible to solve if you're not allowed an array (or something similar) or a library for big integers.

Comment: @molbdnilo printing 1000th Fibonacci number will be difficult without arrays, but printing 100th can be done by using two `long long int` variables to represent one variable. I was writing how to calculate as answer, but unfortunately this question is closed before finishing:(

Answer (score 2):

The 100th Fibonacci number is `218,922,995,834,555,169,026` when `0` is counted as 1st and `1` is counted as 2nd. It is `354,224,848,179,261,915,075` when `0` is counted as 0th and `1` is counted as 1st. The numbers exceeds the maximum value of typical `long long int` (64-bit signed) `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

You can use 2 variables to express one integer by storing the upper and lower half to the variables.

For example, I'll store 12 digits in each variables.

The addition and printing can be done like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(void) {
    const long long int half = 1000000000000LL;
    long long int a_high = 83621143LL, a_low = 489848422977LL;
    long long int b_high = 135301852LL, b_low = 344706746049LL;
    long long int c_high, c_low;

    // c = a + b

    // add each digits
    c_high = a_high + b_high;
    c_low = a_low + b_low;
    // calculate carry
    c_high += c_low / half;
    c_low %= half;

    // print c
    std::cout.fill('0');
    if (c_high > 0) {
        // print higher half, then lower half
        std::cout << c_high << std::setw(12) << c_low;
    } else {
        // higher half is zero, so print lower half only
        std::cout << c_low;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Combining with the Fibonacci program (with a little refinement), it will be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  const long long int half = 1000000000000LL;
  long long int n1_h = 0, n1_l = 0, n2_h = 0, n2_l = 1, n3_h, n3_l, i, number;
  cout << "Enter the number of elements: ";
  cin >> number;
  cout << n1_l << "\n" << n2_l << "\n"; // printing 0 and 1
  // loop starts from 2 because 0 and 1 are already printed
  cout.fill('0');
  for (i = 2; i < number; ++i) {
    // n3 = n1 + n2;
    n3_l = n1_l + n2_l;
    n3_h = n1_h + n2_h + (n3_l / half);
    n3_l %= half;
    // print n3
    if (n3_h > 0) {
      cout << n3_h << setw(12) << n3_l;
    } else {
      cout << n3_l;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    // n1 = n2;
    n1_h = n2_h; n1_l = n2_l;
    // n2 = n3;
    n2_h = n3_h; n2_l = n3_l;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 100th Fibonacci number is 354,224,848,179,261,915,075. so your code is still incorrect

Comment: @student The 100th Fibonacci number is `218922995834555169026` when `0` is 1st and `1` is 2nd. [https://wandbox.org/permlink/4yDRBh4zEvKPHY1k](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4yDRBh4zEvKPHY1k)

Comment: @student The link shows me "404 Not Found". My definition of the order is inherited from your program, so if you say it is wrong your program is wrong not only for the overflow problem.

Comment: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html

Comment: @student OK added explanation based on the definition. It won't affect "print the first 100 Fibonacci numbers" anyway. If you mean "print until 100th" by that, change the loop condition `i < number` to `i <= number`.

Comment: either some comments have been removed or this is really sad. I like the answer. I'd definitely wrap it in a class for more convenient use, but thats just style. Strange that off by one counting can cause such "trouble"